# Create list of lists from list of numbers

Tags: python, list, file

I'm working currently on a basic project, where I want to visualize later some data logged by some sensors.

I have a file with numbers:

```
75
0
0
30
35
32
38
45
53
44
51
62
43
34
56
42
28
32
43
56
43
46
16
33
48
...
```

And I want to create a list of lists, by every sub list will contain 6 element from the original ones, like `[75,0,0,30,35,32],[38,45,53,44,51,62],...]`.

```
f = open("log2.txt", "r")
content = f.readlines()
 
# Variable for storing the sum
idx = 0

line = []
db =  [] 

# Iterating through the content
for number in content:
    print(idx%6)
    if idx % 6 == 0:
        #newline
        db.append(line)
        line = []
        print("AAAAA")
    else:
        #continue line
        line.append(int(number))
    idx += idx+1

print(db)
```

But the result of `db` is only `[[]]`. Why? How can I do it well?

Comment: debugging aside, it may be easiest to create a flat list with all the numbers and then chunk it with one of the methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks).

Comment: `idx += idx+1` doesn't do what you think it does (or is it a typo?), it probably never gets divisible by 6 (except of course for the 1st value which is 0). You meant `idx += 1`. In order to avoid that completely use *enumerate*. You already started debugging by printing *idx*, print some other variables as well, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1(List comprehension):

You can create a list comprehension looping through the lines of `f`:

```
f = open("log2.txt", "r")
content = f.readlines()
l = list(map(int, content)) # Converting each line to integer.
l = [l[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(l), 6)] # Creating lists of 6 elements
print(l)
```

For eg, if a file contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Then the output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

### Method 2(Improvements in your code):

```
f = open("log2.txt", "r")
content = f.readlines()
line = []
db =  [] 

# Iterating through the content
for idx, number in enumerate(content):
    if idx % 6 == 0:
        #newline
        line = [int(number)] # You need to add that number too!
        db.append(line)
    else:
        #continue line
        line.append(int(number))
print(db)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

### What were you doing wrong?

1. Using a variable to keep track of the index. Instead, you can use `enumerate()` to get both the value and the index. Then you won't need to update or initialize `idx`.
2. You were not appending the number when `idx % 6 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/8408137), we can provide a solution with lazy evaluation.

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


f = open("log2.txt", "r")
content = list(int(line) for line in f)

list_of_lists = list(chunks(content, 6))
```

Here we don't keep intermediate data in memory and this approach can be used to process very large files.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("log2.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
content = f.read()

content = content.split()
int_content = []
for i in content:
    int_content.append(int(i))

print(int_content)

final = []
# Iterating through the content
rng = 0
temp = []
for number in int_content:
    if rng != 6:
        temp.append(number)
        print(temp)
        range += 1
        continue
    else:
        rng = 0
        final.append(temp)
        temp = []

print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is much more simple way to do that:

```
f = open("log2.txt", "r")
content = f.readlines()

# now your content looks like this: ['75\n', '0\n', '0\n',...]
content = [int(x.strip()) for x in content]

# now your content looks like this [75, 0, 0, 30, 35, ...]

result = []
while content:
   result.append(content[:6])
   content = content[6:]

# now your result looks like this: [[75, 0, 0, 30, 35, 32], [38, 45, 53, 44, 51, 62],...]
# and your content variable is empty list
```

Comment: I think your solution would have a quadratic complexity O(n^2). 
this operation: `content = content[6:]` required array reallocation and copying.

Comment: That is possible. Question was about "basic project" so I suppose performance isn't the biggest issue here. But that definetely could be optimized if there is lot of data.